# JS - Слово - перевод (привязка слов друг к другу)

Tags: javascript

Как бы вы написали:

Есть слово на английском, к нему есть 5 вариантов перевода. Нужно выбрать правильный.

Как привязать Английское слово к нужному русскому.

Чтобы в рандомном порядке слова выводились и перемешивались после каждого правильного ответа?

Comment: Создаешь класс `Word` в котором есть англ. значение и перевод. Затем создаешь класс `Pool` в котором хранишь коллекцию таких слов (пар значение-перевод) и метод `GetQuestion` который при вызове возвращает экземляр класса `Question` который содержит нужный экземляр `Word` и еще четыре случайно выбранных экземпляра `Word`. В `Question` сделай метод `ShowQuestion` который отдает англ.значение и пять вариантов перевода, а также метод `CheckAnswer`,который проверяет ответ перевод. Как-то так.

Comment: Я делал такой тренажёр на vuejs, на входе от API был json с 4-мя вариантами (один правильный, остальные - нет), далее я этот json обрабатывал на клиенте так, как мне надо. В каком виде у вас приходят данные?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы предложил другую структуру слово и в массиве варианты переводов.

```
const englishWord = {"force":["мощь","сила","могущество","энергия"]};

function shuffle(array) {
    array.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);
    console.log('array: ', array);
    // ['energy', 'могущество', 'сила', 'мощь']

    englishWord.force=array;
  }

shuffle(englishWord.force);
```

Answer (score 1):

Мы бы использовали структуры данных с функцией ключ-значение, либо же использовали поля

```
let world = {     // объект
  correct: "John",  // под ключом "correct" хранится значение "John"
  incorrect: "dontJohn", // под ключом "incorrect" хранится значение "dontJohn"
  incorrect1: "dontJohn1", // под ключом "incorrect1" хранится значение "dontJohn1"
  incorrect2: "dontJohn2", // под ключом "incorrect2" хранится значение "dontJohn2"
  incorrect3: "dontJohn", // под ключом "incorrect3" хранится значение "dontJohn3"
};
```

А что бы использовали вы?

Comment: это ответ или уточняющий вопрос?

Comment: скорее под ключом incorrect проще держать массив